# Data attribute selector to output from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, attributes

This is the first question I am posting so apologies if it's in the wrong format.

Here is my code:

```js
var words = [ ["first"],["second"],["third"] ];

$('.categories li a').click(function() {
    $('.output').empty();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var myEm = $(this +".active").data('words');
    alert(myEm);
    $('.output').append(words[myEm]);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li><a data-words="0">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="1">Second</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="2">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="output"></div>
```

So First, Second and Third are my categories, if you select "First" I want it to output the first array in my html, which is working fine. The issue I am having is I want to have it so if the user selected "First" and "Second" it outputs both of those arrays, but it just chooses the "First" array. Is it an each function I need to use to achieve this?

Hope I have explained this well enough.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe change `$(this +".active")` to `$(this)` so that it would refer to the element that was selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some changes to your code and now it will display all the items that you have selected.

```js
var words = [["first"], ["second"], ["third"]];

            $('.categories li a').click(function () {
                $('.output').empty();
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $('.categories li a.active').each(function (index) {
                    var myEm = $(this).data('words');
                    alert(myEm);
                    debugger;
                    if (words[myEm])
                        $('.output').append(words[myEm]);
                }); 
            });
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li><a data-words="0">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="1">Second</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="2">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was after. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$(this +".active")` looks like an invalid selector.

Replace it with

```
$(this)
```

since you want to refer to the current element anyways.

Also, you need to remove the `active` class from other list elements first before adding to current/clicked element.

```js
var words = [ ["first"],["second"],["third"] ];

$('.categories li a').click(function() {
    $('.output').empty();
    $('.categories li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var myEm = $(this).data('words');
    alert(myEm);
    $('.output').append(words[myEm]);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li><a data-words="0">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="1">Second</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="2">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i've edit a bit of ur code to work fine

```js
var words = [ ["first"],["second"],["third"] ];

$('.categories li a').click(function() {
    //$('.output').empty();
    //$(".categories li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-words');
    alert(myEm);
    $('.output').append(words[myEm]);
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li><a data-words="0">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="1">Second</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="2">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have multiple selection. So if the user selects "First" and "Second" that it outputs [0] and [1] from my "words" which would be:

firstsecond

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more array to store selected data:-

```js
var words = [ ["first"],["second"],["third"] ];
var selectedwords = [];
$('.categories li a').click(function() {
    $('.output').empty();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var myEm = $(this).data('words');
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
     selectedwords.push(words[myEm]);
   }else{
     var index = selectedwords.indexOf(words[myEm]);
      selectedwords.splice( index, 1 );
  }
    alert(myEm);
    $('.output').append(selectedwords.toString());
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li><a data-words="0">First</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="1">Second</a></li>
  <li><a data-words="2">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="output"></div>
```